# iFrames - Not able to locate through Selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, iframe

I have seen lot of responses about switching to iframes like
driver.switchTo().frame("test frame"); and driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

However, i'm unable to proceed to MenuFrame 4 in the below code. I'm using Java, Please help!!!!!

Comment: Please always provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. In addition, describe what you already tried.

Comment: <iframe name="pb_5263" title="Cust Order Menu" id="ivuFrm_pivu0">
<html>
<head>
<body class="Webgui" id="webgui">
<div id="SBusyDiv">
<iframe class="NewMenuFrame" id="MenuFrame0">
<iframe class="NewMenuFrame" id="MenuFrame1" src="/sap/public/bc/its/mimes/system/sl/page/menubase.html" scrolling="no" application="YES">
<iframe class="NewMenuFrame" id="MenuFrame2" src="/sap/public/bc/its/mimes/system/sl/page/menubase.html" scrolling="no" application="YES">
<iframe class="NewMenuFrame" id="MenuFrame4" src="/sap/public/bc/its/mimes/system/sl/page/menubase.html" scrolling="no" application="YES">

Comment: Please add the code snippet you've used to switch to the frame. Also, in this case if you can upload an image of the relevant frame(s), that will be helpful too. Please [take the help of imgur](http://imgur.com/) to upload the relevant image and add link here as your rep is tad low to upload one directly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The below option worked for me -

driver.switchTo().frame(); and then after it switched to it, i used
driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); before going into the next frame.

I spent a lot of time looking for this. Hope it helps others caught in similar despair.

Thanks all.

Comment: Glad it worked... Always remember when you have nested iframes the best part is to switch to default content to be on safer side and start traversing again from root, though it increases rendering time but what matters is to successfully detect the frame. Also i have updated my answer too as per your question

Answer (score 0):

In your case all the iframes are nested. So to go into iframe '*MenuFrame 4*' you can use below code

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.tagName("iframe")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("MenuFrame0")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("MenuFrame1")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("MenuFrame2")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("MenuFrame4")));
```

Comment: Downvoter, please add the reason why you have downvoted for this answer.

Comment: @Subh :Yes True,Not sure what's wrong. I Re-checked my code cannot figure out the reason.but not to worry. Will keep it posting at our Best.